Blazor WASM Tasks
I have just seen that Blazor WASM does not currently support multiple threads. So if you do a Task.Run() it will actually run on the main thread and block the UI.
So if I wanted a Blazor WASM application that did some expensive processing. For example
a) A computationally expensive numerical computation
await Task.Run(() => SlowComputation())

or
b) Performing a slow query in a SQLite DB
would I essentially just have to accept that the UI will be blocked?
I'm currently in the process of converting a winforms app to Blazor wasm and we use Task.Run() quite frequently.

Any processor intensive operation such as a heavy duty computation will block the thread: there's only one.  Consider handing off to an API.
Any I/0 activity will not: there's no actual thread being used to wait on say the network subsystem returning the requested data.   So calling Task.Run() in such circumstances is pointless.  If you want an explanation see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html.
You can't call a SQLite DB from the browser, that's got to go through an API.

It's a client side WASM app, there is no web API, everything is local

Computational processor intensive applications are not good candidates for WASM.  And there can be no SQLite DB.
